# Have you ever gotten hit?

Tags: grammar

Is the following question correct?

"Have you ever gotten hit on the nose by someone?"

Meaning the following:

"Have someone ever hit you on the nose?"

Comment: The sentence is perfectly idiomatic, and I've heard similar in conversation countless times.  As a written sentence, it has a slightly young or uneducated feel, though.

Comment: Well maybe the uneducated feeling it's because that's what I'm an uneducated person trying to learn (: thank you for you comment sir.

Comment: I wasn't trying to criticize you, but only to answer your question.  And I didn't mean to imply it would make you sound like a rube or anything. It really does sound fine.  It's just the kind of phrasing I'd expect to hear more often from a teenager than from an adult.

Comment: Ok Jonah, it's all good it didn't feel like if you were criticizing but making a point and answering my question. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the OP's question is correct grammatically; it conveys the same sense as the second question.

Has someone ever hit you on the nose?

This sentence is in the active voice.  It can be changed into the passive as follows:

Have you ever been hit on the nose by someone?

If you want to be informal in your conversation or writing, you can use 'get' instead of 'be' to form the passive as follows:

Have you ever gotten hit on the nose by someone?

Comment: Thank you Khan your answer it is very clear It has gotten me out doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Although your sentence is understandable

> Have you ever gotten hit on the nose by someone?

a better way to phrase it might be

> Have you ever **been** hit on the nose by someone?
>   Have you ever **been punched in** the nose?

in the latter sentence, "by someone" is implied since it would usually be understood that a person would do the punching (except possibly if kangaroos were involved).

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. Now let me tell you something I was taught that get equals be in passive voice but I'm not sure if that question is in passive voice. ): can you tell?

Comment: Can someone tell me if my first example is in passive voice?

Comment: Yes it is passive voice, "***Have*** you ***ever been*** hit by someone?"

Comment: Wait a minute Peter that's your example and I was asking about my example "have you ever gotten hit  on the nose by someone"

Comment: It's the same, you're just using ***get*** instead of ***be***. Having said that, try not to use ***gotten***, "Have you ever **got** hit on the nose?", "Yeah, I **got** hit on the nose once, with a baseball." which has a US Midwestern kind of dialect to it.  I was taught early on: "Don't say gotten 'cause it rhymes with rotten."

Comment: Oh yeah hahaha that's really funny gotten and rotten you know what I used say got for past participle but I was later taught to use gotten for past participle in American English but I don't know that might be wrong